# Itunes: Updating podcasts on more than one computer

Tags: windows, itunes, ipod

I listen to a lot of podcasts, and would like to be able to update my Ipod with fresh podcasts both at home and at my office (different computers). Same issue when I travel, I would like to use my laptop to get the latest subscribed podcasts, even though I am not at my main computer, where I have everything today.

How can I do that?

I am on the Windows platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can but when you sync the ipod with any particular PC, itunes will wipe all existing podcasts (in the ipod) and sync the ones from the local library.

Answer (score 2):

I do that all the time. You just have to be sure to set your music to not sync automatically. You can still leave podcasts syncing automatically and they will work just fine. iTunes only wipes your library if you try to sync DRM protected items.

Comment: Going to go try this out, and if it works, you're my new hero (in spite of making me feel like a dunce for just assuming it wouldn't work).  ;)

Comment: So other than making sure music does not autosync, do you just simply make Itunes on two computers get the podcasts and set it to sync? 

It sounds almost too good to be true! :D

Comment: I was unable to make this work. Whatever I do, ITunes insists on deleting the podcasts on the device, and then syncs fine (while keeping its hands off my music). But if I then later want to update my podcasts from another computer (home/work for instance) - I lose all the podcasts already on the device. Am I missing something, or is this the "feature"?